# Why do I have an error 400 in my ajax request?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-web-api

partial html code:

```
<h1>Registration</h1>
<form id="loginform">
    <input type="number" name="Id" value="0" id="ID"/><br />
    <p>Имя</p>
    <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name" /><br />
    <p>Ник</p>
    <input type="text" name="NickName" id="NickName" /><br />
    <p>Возраст</p>
    <input type="number" name="Age" id="Age" /><br />
    <p>Почта</p>
    <input type="text" name="Email" id="Email" /><br />
    <p>Пароль</p>
    <input type="text" name="Password" id="Password" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="отправить" id="Submit" />
</form>

<script>
    function submitForm(form, url) {
       // let formData = $(form).serialize();
var person = new Object();
person.Id = $("#ID").val();
person.Name = $("#Name").val();
person.Age = $("#Age").val();
person.NickName = $("#NickName").val();
person.Email = $("#Email").val();
person.Password = $("#Password").val();
        let response = "";
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            data:person,

            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
})
        return response;
    }
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Submit").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            let data = submitForm($("#loginform"), "/api/Test");
            console.log(data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

Api controller with Registration method:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    Context db;
    public TestController(Context context)
    {
        db = context;
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Registration([FromBody] User user) 
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Users.Add(user);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return Ok(user);
        }
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
}
```

Simple model of user:

```
    public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string NickName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Where did I make a mistake in my ajax request?

In html: I have got the same result without input with name="id".

In Registration method: `[FromBody]` and `[FromForm]` did not help too

In JQuery code: `JSON.stringify(person)` and `$("#loginform").serializeArray()` did not work  too

Comment: To send json you need to stringify it yourself

Comment: @charlietfl, I have tried. JSON.stringify(person)

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62292252/edit) to show what your code looks like now

Comment: @freedomn-m OP would have to use `[FromForm]` in that case. They should also be able to use `[FromBody]` as long as they stringify the request body as JSON as has been suggested

Comment: @Phil, it works fine, thanks. But now I have error 500 because user has id, age=0 and other properties =null.